# Android app launches slow on notification tap

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm using FCM to send push notifications to my app; the expected behaviour when the user taps the notification is to launch the app as normal, like tapping the launcher app icon.

At the moment, when user tap on the notification, spend more than 30 seconds before app is opened. Notification go away, but the app does not opens... Not even a white screen, nothing.

When `onMessageReceived` is triggered, `displayNotification` method is called.

```
private void displayNotification(String title, String body) {

    createNotificationChannel();
    PendingIntent contentIntent = generateNotificationContentIntent();

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CONTENTS_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_no_bg_white)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), notificationBuilder.build());
}

private PendingIntent generateNotificationContentIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);
    return stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        return;
    }

    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CONTENTS_CHANNEL_ID, CONTENTS_CHANNEL_ID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    notificationChannel.setDescription(CONTENTS_CHANNEL_ID);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

}
```

My onCreate MainActivity method simply checks wether the user is logged, and if so, launches the HomeActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

    //Read shared preferences.
    sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if(sharedPref.contains("token") || sharedPref.getBoolean("isGuest", false)){
        //Redirect to home
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class );
        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
        finish();
    }

    loadTowns(this);

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE: Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="my.awesome.package">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.vansuita.pickimage.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/picker_provider_paths" />
    </provider>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/logo_no_bg_white" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ChannelProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/channel"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TownProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/town"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ContentActivity"
        android:label="@string/content"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ContentsListActivity"
        android:label="@string/contents"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".QuestionResultsActivity"
        android:label="@string/question"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ForgetPasswordActivity"
        android:label="@string/DidYouForgetPassword"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ValidationProcesActivity"
        android:label="@string/verify_user"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".QuestionVoteActivity"
        android:label="@string/question"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NewUserActivity"
        android:label="@string/new_user"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".NewUserSuccessActivity"
        android:label="@string/new_user"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme" />

    <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".NotificationsActivity"
        android:label="@string/notifications"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewNotificationActivity"
        android:label="@string/notifications"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".NewFriendshipRequestActivity"
        android:label="@string/notifications"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme" />

    <activity
        android:name=".TypeUserSelectionActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SelectTownActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteActionBarTheme" />
</application>
```

Comment: Can you please show manifest file ?

Comment: Sure @Nakul , I posted it, thanks :)

Comment: Does `loadTowns()` do any network-related activity?

Comment: Hi @greeble31 , yes, it is! But it is a non-blocking API call; in fact, the app can start without Internet. And, even if the app would make the API call before launch the activity, it is less than a second time to get the response. Thanks for your comment! 

Comment: Well that's what I was angling at; the likelihood is that your main thread is blocked for some reason. If you can reproduce this issue with a debugger attached, I would recommend breaking into the debugger during that 30 second period, and examining the state of thread "main".

Comment: How do you solve this?? I have exactly the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Add PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT to your pending intent.

```
stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Also add **android:exported="true"** to the activity tag in manifest

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer.
Could you explain me how this will work to solve the problem?
I read on documentation about `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`: Flag indicating that this PendingIntent can be used only once; and about `exported`: Whether or not components of other applications can invoke the service or interact with it.

Does not sounds to me related to my topic; although, I will try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is working for me.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        /*flags for resume activity*/
        notificationIntent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        /*for clear notification on click*/
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
```